# Most efficient way to delete thousands of entities in datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

This is how I delete thousands of entities in datastore: First, get 1st entity. If 1st entity exist, fetch 500 entities to delete. Second, defers `deletealltarget` again and again until 1st entity does not exist.

```
def deletealltarget(twaccount_db_key):
  target_db = model.Target.query().filter(ndb.GenericProperty('twaccount_key') == twaccount_db_key).get()
  if target_db:
    target_dbs = model.Target.query().filter(ndb.GenericProperty('twaccount_key') == twaccount_db_key).fetch(500,keys_only=True)
    ndb.delete_multi(target_dbs)
    deferred.defer(deletealltarget,twaccount_db_key)
```

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`delete_multi_async`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/functions) asynchronously, instead of using `defer`, but besides that, you are doing good with this way. For example, you are using other advices already told, like using [`keys_only`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126881/how-efficient-is-google-app-engine-ndb-delete-multi).

Google recommends using [this Dataflow template](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/bulk-delete) for bulk deletion., but I don't know if it fits your scenario.